# IOS SWIFT: Declaration is only valid at file scope

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Normally in C# I used to implement extension methods in a separate class (named 'ExtensionMethods') and used in the project.

Here in my first swift iphone App I need to implement some extension methods to 'String' class but providing me with this error

[image]

This works perfect with swift Playground but not sure how to use in a real project. really appreciate if someone can guide me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Your extensions declarations should not be inside a class, but *at file scope* like the message says. :)

Comment: Yes, as u can see in the image they are in the 'ExtensionMethods' class... I'm NOT clear about what it means by file scope in here. Thanks

Comment: Read my comment again: I said they *should not be* in the class like you did. Antonio has made a nice detailed answer. File scope: root level of your code, not inside an object, class or anything.

Comment: Yes, got the point. Completely different than in C#...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The extension must be at the root level - don't embed them into a class or whatever. So just write:

```
import UIKit

extension String {
    var doubleValue: Double {
        ...
    }
}

extension String {
    func doubleValueT() -> Double {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that you can also combine them into a single extension:

```
import UIKit

extension String {
    var doubleValue: Double {
        ...
    }

    func doubleValueT() -> Double {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: "The extension must be at the root level" where did you read this?