# declaration is only valid at file a scope (don't know what that means)

Tags: swift

I am working on a app that is trying to make a customizable border size for photos. So all of the sides in the border will not be the same width. I got extension ca layer online and was told it would allow me to create a border where each side will have a customizable width. I just don't know where in the code ca layer goes.

```
import UIKit

class x1ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var imageDisplay: UIImageView!
     var screenView: UIImageView!




    extension CALayer {

        func addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge, color: UIColor, thickness: CGFloat) {

            let border = CALayer();

            switch edge {
            case UIRectEdge.top:
                border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: thickness)
                break
            case UIRectEdge.bottom:
                border.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:self.frame.height - thickness, width:self.frame.width, height:thickness)
                break
            case UIRectEdge.left:
                border.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: thickness, height: self.frame.height)
                break
            case UIRectEdge.right:
                border.frame = CGRect(x:self.frame.width - thickness, y: 0, width: thickness, height:self.frame.height)
                break
            default:
                break
            }

            border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor;

            self.addSublayer(border)
        }

    }


@IBAction func camera(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self




        imageDisplay.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 1.0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
        imageDisplay.layer.cornerRadius = 1
        imageDisplay.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageDisplay.layer.borderWidth = 1


        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)}}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject]!){
    imageDisplay.image = image
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
    screenView = UIImageView()

    screenView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)




    let text = "#HAPPY"
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 125, y: 700, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 300))
    label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 122)

    label.textColor = UIColor.blue
    label.alpha = 1.0
    label.text = text


    self.view.addSubview(screenView)
    self.view.addSubview(label)


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageDisplay.frame.size)
    self.view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)

}
@IBAction func save(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Image Saved", message: "Image is in photo gallery", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okay = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okay)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)



    let photo = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(photo!, nil, nil, nil)

}


}
```

Comment: You need to put it at file scope (i.e not in a type or function), just as the error says.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOS SWIFT: Declaration is only valid at file scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344854/ios-swift-declaration-is-only-valid-at-file-scope)

Comment: can you give me a example of a file scope @Hamish

Comment: The linked Q&A does just that :)

Comment: @Hamish I looked at the q and a it was very straight forward but will the border work outside of the class?

Comment: Not sure what you mean – once the extension is at file scope, you'll be able to call `addBorder(edge:color:thickness:)` on a `CALayer` instance. Have you tried putting it at file scope and calling the method?